# Entity Framework - Rollback for Mix of Stored Procedures and Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I need to call a few stored procedures (data inserts) plus update an entity value to the database.

I want these operations to be atomic, so if an error occurs, they all rollback.

In my code, if I force an exception to observe the behavior of the rollback, my entity changes are rolling back, but my stored procedure changes do not get rolled back.

Looking at the implementation for unit of work, it's just looking at `_context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` - I assume completely ignoring any stored procedure changes?

When I change the unit of work implementation to use

```
new System.Transactions.TransactionScope()
```

the rollback works as expected.

Should I be using `new System.Transactions.TransactionScope()`? Are there any gotchas?

**Code**

```
...
using (var scope = _unitOfWork.Begin())
{
    try
    {                    
        var outcome = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SOME EXEC COMMAND", parameters);        

        throw new Exception("Something happened");

        scope.Commit(); // Never gets called because of Exception                  
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        scope.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Unit of work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, ITransaction
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private bool _committed;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public ITransaction Begin()
    {
        _committed = false;
        return this;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
        _committed = true;
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        foreach (var entry in _context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    entry.Reload();
                    break;
                case EntityState.Detached:
                    break;
                case EntityState.Unchanged:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing) 
            return;

        if (!_committed)
        {
            Rollback();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes - the Change Tracker of course can only track whatever you've changing / modifying / adding through means of the `DbContext` class.

Running a stored procedure is outside the scope of the EF Change Tracker - so if you base your "rollback" on simply things in the Change Tracker, you won't be able to properly handle anything your stored procedure have done.

Using `TransactionScope` is fundamentally different - this is an "umbrella" over all the database operations - including any stored procedures being executed - since it's basically on the database's level. So rolling back based on the transaction scope will roll back all database operations - whether handled via the EF `DbContext`, or via other means.

Comment: Is this the recommended approach when using a mix of Stored Procedures and Entity Framework entities? I might be in the case of "you don't know what you don't know"

Comment: @SebastianPatten: well, since executing stored procedures happens "behind the back" of EF - then yes, if you want to ensure integrity and consistency across both EF operations and executions of stored procedures, then this is - as far as I know - the recommend best practice, since it works at the ADO.NET/SQL Server level and handles both kinds of operations