# EF change tracker and stored procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My model is using a database-first approach where stored procedures are not imported and exist only in the database.

I need to execute my stored procedures via `ExecuteSqlCommand` and I would like to track those changes, but unfortunately entities modified by executing stored procedures (insert, delete) are not listed in `ChangeTracker().Entries`.

I've tried:

```cs
context.Database.BeginTransaction();

var result = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(storedProcedureName, parameters);

var trackedEntities = context.ChangeTracker
                             .Entries()
                             .Where(x => x.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
                             .ToList();

context.Database.CurrentTransaction.Commit();
```

I've also tried to dig in current transaction but actually there is nothing that I could use. Next idea was to force my Entity to get in change tracker with state unmodified with querying it via linq and than run stored procedure but it seems it's not tracked ad all.

I'm out of ideas. This is required to rollback changes done by stored procedures after test finish.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The procedure is executed on the SGBD and EF has no hint about the executed modifications by the procedure.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron it's ver 6

Comment: EF does not track the results of stored procedures executed this way it just executes them SQL server side .

Comment: Well, is there any way to reach that via sqltransaction ? and ExecuteNonQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(String, Object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0):

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic type. The type can be any type that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query, or can be a simple primitive type. The type does not have to be an entity type. The results of this query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object returned is an entity type.

Or [`DbSet<TEntity>.SqlQuery(String, Object[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#system-data-entity-dbset-1-sqlquery(system-string-system-object())):

> Creates a raw SQL query that will return entities in this set. By default, the entities returned are tracked by the context;

Comment: There was a topic with really similar problem where user [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729843/entity-framework-rollback-for-mix-of-stored-procedures-and-entities) used TransactionScope() and tracker somehow was able to track those changes. I know that TS() is somehow Umbrella for all transactions done against DB but i'm not really able to reach this out. I will try to use SqlQuery